# Which hook to add action on specific page?

Tags: actions

I tried to remove action added by a plugin only for specific posts.

But I can't find the hook to get the page ID currently edited (wp-admin/post.php?post=112) and add action conditionnally.

Here's the code :

```
// Deactivate plugin Resize at Upload Plus on page id=112
remove_action('wp_handle_upload', 'hz_uploadresize_resize');
add_action('wp_loaded','custom_upload_resize');
function custom_upload_resize(){
    $id = get_the_ID();
    if (isset($id) && $id !== 112){
        add_action('wp_handle_upload', 'hz_uploadresize_resize');
    }
}
```

The plugin resizes images after uploading
http://wordpress.org/plugins/resize-at-upload-plus/

Can you help please ?

Comment: Just a guess but thinking `$id !=='`112'` is too strict a comparison. Won't `$id` be an integer, and not a string? Either lose a `=` or lose the apostrophies `''`

Answer (score 2):

`wp_loaded` hook is too early for environment to be completed and for conditionals to work.

You need to do this a little later, for example on `admin_head` hook.

PS also use [`get_the_ID()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_id/) for cleaner look :)

Comment: Thanks, it helps. But any condition is ignored. I still find a solution :)